# Standard notation for discrete and continuous functions?

Tags: probability, discrete-calculus, continuity

Is there some some standard notation for denoting discrete functions (say $f^{d}(x)$ to distinguish them from (their) continuous (counterpart) functions (say $f^{c}(x)$)?

Comment: Not that I know of.. Usually it is inferred from the rule of the function itself.

Comment: If it's the function that is "discrete" then the term "simple function" probably covers it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_function . If its the domain then I don't know.